# Deferred custom action after install with parameters

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to modify system state(creating credentials) using values entered by used on dialog before install dialog. Since I'm going to modify system I need to run my code in deferred custom action. But my problem is passing parameters from edit boxes to custom action. How Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

deferred action didn`t allow you the access session variables.
and you will not able to call deferred custom actions before Install dialog.

I think you want to perform some action on button click.
so you have to use custom actions of immediate type where u can easily access the your installer properties and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in visibility of variables. The solution was to make them public(use upper case names) and use them in immediate custom action)